# TidHttp post with URL-Segment

Tags: json, rest, delphi, post, indy

I am using the TidHttp-component to do a post to an endpoint that has a URL-Segment parameter, and also JSON-data in the Custom Header. In the REST-Debugger everything works, but I do not know how to add the parameters in code.
In essence my code looks like this :

---

```
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json' ;
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization',Token );
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Api-Key',APIKEY );

//deliveryOrderId is a URL-SEGMENt, HOW ??
// this does not work ?
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('deliveryOrderId', deliveryOrderID );

 url := ‘https://api.staging.floriday.io/apps/delivery-orders/{deliveryOrderId}/auction’

streamParameters := TStringStream.Create( makeDeliveryOrderJSON ) ;

IdHTTP1.Post( url , streamParameters) ;  <---- BAD REQUEST
```

---

Below some screenshots of the REST-Debugger,

any help is very much appreciated !

kind regards,

Dirk.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `TIdHTTP` doesn't support named URL segment parameters. On the other hand [TRestClient](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/REST_Client_Library), which is what REST Debugger uses behind the scenes, does. If you insist on using Indy, you have to manage URL yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL-Segments are a feature of Embarcadero's REST framework, they are not part of the actual HTTP request itself, and don't apply to other HTTP libraries, like Indy's `TIdHTTP`.  What you are looking for is a simple string substitution in the URL itself, eg:

```pascal
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json' ;
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', Token);
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Api-Key', APIKEY);

url := 'https://api.staging.floriday.io/apps/delivery-orders/{deliveryOrderId}/auction';
url := StringReplace(url, '{deliveryOrderId}', deliveryOrderID);
// or simply:
// url := 'https://api.staging.floriday.io/apps/delivery-orders/' + deliveryOrderID + '/auction';

streamParameters := TStringStream.Create(makeDeliveryOrderJSON);

IdHTTP1.Post(url, streamParameters);
```